# Describing the shape formed by crushing malleable cubes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, metals

I just watched a video of cubes of various metals being crushed by a hydraulic press (on the hydraulic press channel). Two of the cubes (made of somewhat stronger materials) deformed into an interesting shape that looked like the silhouette of a circle and square super-imposed on each other.

You can see the shape I'm describing in this video: https://youtu.be/4f7-5H3xDlE?t=374 at time 6:14.

My question is: how does one mathematically describe the shape that is formed?

My intuition tells me that the strength of the material only effects the amount of force needed to deform it, not the shape to which it deforms. Thus all that should matter should be the height of the resulting shape.

Is it possible to come up with a formula to describe the shape obtained by crushing a 1x1x1 cube of malleable material to a height of x via uniform force application in the z axis?

What would the formula be?

Comment: You want an analytical expression for the plasticity of steel? If it even exists it's probably a full page to write it out. Go with "squashed" or "bulging" here.

Comment: Not the plasticity, I want an analytical expression for the shape of a deformed cube assuming "infinite" malleability. The material doesn't really matter I don't think.